# React-Bootstrap Navbar - How to utilize grid system to add offset or shift items to the right?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

So I am creating a personal site using react-bootstrap. And here is what the site looks like right now. 
[image: Picture of the nav bar and intro]

The navbar is

```
<Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
            <Nav>
                <Nav.Link href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
            <Nav className="ml-auto">
                <Nav.Link href="#deets">More deets</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link eventKey={2} href="#memes">
                    Dank memes
                </Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
```

and the introduction looks like

```
<Row>
            <Col md={{ span: 4, offset: 2 }}>
                <p id='hey'>Hey, I am Max! </p> </Col> </Row>
```

I really want to shift the navbar to the right with "offset: 2" so that the brand ("React-Bootstrap" in the navbar) can line up with the "Hey, I am Max". I've tried adding padding or margin to Navbar.Brand but it doesn't really work. Is there a way for me to directly add offset:2 to the Navbar.Brand element? Or what might be the best way to accomplish this?